# How does this ldapsearch command succeed without using the intermediate certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ldap

I have an LDAP server (Active Directory domain controller) with a certificate that is signed by an internal intermediary CA and that of course is signed by an internal root CA. I feel like I am overlooking something fundamental about PKI here because I thought I needed both the intermediary CA and root CA files on the client side to establish trust with the cert that the LDAP server presents, so I don't understand why both of these commands are successful. They're identical except that the first one trusts both the root CA and intermediary CA whereas the second ONLY trusts the root cert. I expected the first command to work but not the second. (I have double-checked that the output is identical even when not using `grep` and that the contents of the .crt files is correct.)

What am I misunderstanding?

```
export LDAPTLS_CACERT=./chained.crt; ldapsearch -x -W -h ldap.example.com -p 389 -ZZ -D "testuser@example.com" -b "OU=users,OU=example,DC=com" "(cn=testuser)" | grep result
Enter LDAP Password: 
result: 0 Success

export LDAPTLS_CACERT=./root_cert_only.crt; ldapsearch -x -W -h ldap.example.com -p 389 -ZZ -D "testuser@example.com" -b "OU=users,OU=example,DC=com" "(cn=testuser)" | grep result
Enter LDAP Password:
result: 0 Success

# and just for fun, let's try it without trusting any CAs. it fails as expected.
export LDAPTLS_CACERT=''; ldapsearch -x -W -h ldap.example.com -p 389 -ZZ -D "testuser@example.com" -b "OU=users,OU=example,DC=com" "(cn=testuser)"
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
    additional info: TLS error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
```

Note: I learned the hard way that `ldapsearch` on macOS does not support trusting certs via a path set in an environment variable. The output above is from linux (`ldapsearch` version 2.4.40)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command (with both root and subordinate CAs) works because your client trusts the root certificate explicitly - it's in the trust-anchor store - and this root has signed the subordinate CA certificate, therefore your client implicitly trust that too.

The second command works because the TLS specification [states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) that servers **must** send all certificates required to validate the server certificate.  Therefore your LDAP server sends its certificate, followed by the subordinate CA certificate.

Effectively, both commands are the same.  In the fist example, the client receives the subordinate CA certificate from both the command line and from the server.

Note that the server does not need to send the root certificate as that must already be installed on your client and trusted.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense now. I did not realize that the LDAP server was presenting its own cert AND the intermediate cert in every connection negotiation (I can see this with `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ldap.example.com:636`), so now I understand why both `ldapsearch` commands work.